# Excel-like "% of total rows" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is an option in Excel called "% of total rows".

Is it possible to simulate it in python?

**Example:**

| sellers | seller1 | seller2 | seller3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sales | 1 | 1 |  |
| shoes | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| shirts | 1 |  | 1 |
| hats | 1 | 1 |  |

With that property it can be modified and it would look like this:

| sellers | seller1 | seller2 | seller3 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sales | 50% | 50% |  | 100% |
| shoes | 33.3% | 33.3% | 33.3% | 100% |
| shirts | 50% |  | 50% | 100% |
| hats | 50% | 50% |  | 100% |

[I load the data from a csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp53f.png)

[Here I was able to get the totals but I cannot generate the percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75jPp.png)

df.pivot_table(index="CODIGO", columns="NOMBRE", values="COPIACOD", aggfunc="count", margins = True,fill_value = "0")
df2=df.pivot_table(index="CODIGO", columns="NOMBRE", values="COPIACOD",
aggfunc="count", margins = True,fill_value = "0", margins_name='Total')
df2

I already solved it with the suggestion you gave me

Thank you

Comment: Please explain what you mean exactly, try to post a screenshot here and tell us what you have tried so far. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! All parts of your post should be written in English, including the title.

Comment: Sure it is. However, we're going to need more details to answer your question. Did you read your excel sheet? Are you using pandas? What did you try to get the `% of row total` value in python for your data? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that with Excel, it's just a matter of clicks to get to that, and there surely must be a smarter solution involving pivoting the dataframe (pandas.pivot_table), but if I can suggest a simple data manipulation solution, here it is:

```
#Preparing the input data:
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['sellers']=pd.Series(['sales','shoes','shirts','hats'])
df['seller1']=pd.Series([1,1,1,1])
df['seller2']=pd.Series([1,1,None,1])
df['seller3']=pd.Series([None,1,1,None])

#Create a static copy of your dataframe and sum over column values (axis=1)
df0=df.copy().sum(axis=1)
# Then divide each column by the sum of its respective row
df['seller1 %']=df['seller1']/(df0)*100
df['seller2 %']=df['seller2']/(df0)*100
df['seller3 %']=df['seller3']/(df0)*100

df
```